# DIV position issue with IE10

Tags: html, css

Would you know why on IE10 my "error" message overlaps the "Envoyer/Submit" button in my form, and also how to fix this? It works fine on safari so not sure what the issue is. Also .error has a `float: left` but doesn't seem to work.
Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u6Kre/

Thanks for your help

```
.error {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    display: block;
    background: #EF6666;
    display: inline;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    top: 210px;
    float: left;
}
```

Form not looking OK (ie. with IE10)

[image: IE10 issue]

Form looking OK (i.e. with Safari)

[image: Form OK with Safari]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you dont need `float: left` with absolute positions and `display: inline` also not needed as , elements absolutely positioned are treated as `display: block`, do:

```
.error {
    position: absolute;
    background: #EF6666;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    top: 210px;
    left: 0; //to show it on left
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.error {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    display: block;
    background: #EF6666;
    display: inline;
    padding: 3px 10px 3px 10px;
    top: 210px;
    left:0px;
}
```